# Microsoft Windows 10 "remove everything" keeps user name

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd, secure-erase

I am trying to secure wipe my laptop's ssd drive with the Windows 10 "remove everything" option from "Start > Settings > Update & security > Recovery."

Supposedly, this should remove all traces of personal information and reset the laptop to its original state.  At least everything that I could find suggests that's the case.

However, after performing this operation (it took about 2 hours to complete) I saw that there was still a "windows.old" folder on the drive.  Within this one, there was a folder with my username (if I remember correctly it was in windows.old->users->myoldusername).  That particular folder seemed empty, but I found this to be extremely concerning, to say the least.

I thought that all traces of any previous users should have been wiped from the computer!  If the user name persists, what else is on there???

Has anyone else noticed this?  If so, can you shed some light as to what's going on?

Comment: Just remove that directory.

Comment: "Supposedly, this should remove all traces of personal information and reset the laptop to its original state." - Incorrect;  "At least everything that I could find suggests that's the case." - See my answer on the subject.  " Within this one, there was a folder with my username (if I remember correctly it was in windows.old->users->myoldusername)." - So use Disk Cleanup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Windows 10 gets "updated" (Fall Creators Update, etc.) or reset, it makes a backup of all the data located at the Windows drive (usually C:) to the **Windows.old** folder, so that if you change your mind, you can revert the action, whether it is an update or a reset. When you do a reset, it will revert everything to their default state while keeping a backup. It doesn't mean that it will wipe the whole drive.

If you want to delete that backup, you can do a *Disk Cleanup* (`cleanmgr.exe`) to clean that folder, or manually delete it.

If you want to perform a clean reset, then you may want to reinstall the original version of Windows installed in your computer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I guess that I was under the mistaken assumption that the "remove everything" option was safe to use if you wanted to do something like sell your computer.  I will make sure to run a Disk Cleanup afterwards.